# Why ngPattern, ngMinvalue and other validation directives are applicable only for <input>

Tags: angularjs, validation

I discovered that following Angular code doesn't work

```
<div ng-model="..." ng-pattern="...">
```

because Angular has the restriction

```
var ALIASED_ATTR = {
  'ngMinlength': 'minlength',
  'ngMaxlength': 'maxlength',
  'ngMin': 'min',
  'ngMax': 'max',
  'ngPattern': 'pattern'
};

function getAliasedAttrName(element, name) {
  var nodeName = element.nodeName;
  return (nodeName === 'INPUT' || nodeName === 'TEXTAREA') && ALIASED_ATTR[name];
}
```

The validators will work only with input and textarea but it will be convinied e.g. for solving the usecase and many others

```
<div contenteditable ngModel="...">
```

Why angular has the restriction?

Comment: I don't know for certain, since I have not contributed to AngularJS at all, but I would assume that they wanted to avoid that complexity. I would assume that validating a form element is pretty different than validating a regular div.  Why wouldn't you use a text area for this? Are you building a CMS or something?

Comment: Not actually, I'm working on complex component with different input fields and the component has a result value as a concatenation of all nested fields. The value is not visible but should be validated. I'd like to use standard Angular validators but unable.  of course I can use `<input type="text" ng-model="..." ng-show="false" ng-pattern="">` but it's bad practise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug, the issue has been already fixed.

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/43769fb676ae904852582a2c88a5523f0b9f58fc

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/12658